# ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}

Tags: android, google-api-client, android-tv, google-nearby

Implemented [this sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby) on mobile & tablet everything is perfect ! But whit Android TV ADT-1 v5.0.2 build LRX22G these eloquent message shows up.

```
GmsClient: unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.service.NearbyMessagesService.START

D/NearbyMessagesClient: Failed to emit client lifecycle event ACTIVITY_STOPPED due to GmsClient being disconnected

NearbyMessagesClient: Failed to emit client lifecycle event CLIENT_DISCONNECTED due to GmsClient being disconnected
```

The callback :

```
@Override public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult)
```

Outputs :

```
ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}
```

Like I said, everything works in the mobile module. I doubled checked API_KEY, gradle dependencies, Manifest meta, nope, I even created a listing for the APK and created a Game on Google Play Console, nothing.

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Had (actually still have) same problem with Sony KDL-55W75xC Android TV.

Pulled down `com.google.android.gms` package from both TV and HTC phone and sadly one from TV doesn't contain `NearbyMessagesService` service at all. It's not included in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Also there is no code for it in the APK file.

Both packages seem to have similar version name:

Sony:

> versionCode: '8703836' versionName: 8.7.03 (2645110-836)

HTC:

> versionCode: '8703238'   versionName: 8.7.03 (2645110-238)

But one on Sony TV has higher versionCode. Sadly because of that, it's not possible to update `gms` package on the TV using one from HTC because of `INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE` error.